# JQuery script not working on Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

The following script works on IE and Firefox but I can't seem to figure out the reason why it's not working on Chrome and Safari. The purpose of the script is simply to remove the first 4 options from list "B" if the first option in list "A" is clicked.

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

```js
 $("document").ready(function () {
     $('select[name="A"] option[value="001"]').click(function () {
         var vList = ["001", "002", "003", "004"];
         $.each(vList, function (i, code) {
             $("select[name="B"] option[value=" + vList[i] + "]").remove();
         });
     });
 });
```

```html
<select name="A" value="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="001">1 RED CATEGORY</option>
    <option value="002">2 BLUE CATEGORY</option>
    <option value="003">3 GREEN CATEGORY</option>
    <option value="004">4 YELLOW CATEGORY</option>
    <option value="005">5 BLACK CATEGORY</option>
</select>


<select name="B" value="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="001">1 - RED</option>
    <option value="002">2 - RED</option>
    <option value="003">3 - RED</option>
    <option value="004">4 - RED</option>
    <option value="005">1 - BLUE</option>
    <option value="006">2 - BLUE</option>
    <option value="007">3 - BLUE</option>
    <option value="008">4 - BLUE</option>
    <option value="009">1 - GREEN</option>
    <option value="010">2 - GREEN</option>
    <option value="011">3 - GREEN</option>
    <option value="012">4 - GREEN</option>
    <option value="013">1 - YELLOW</option>
    <option value="014">2 - YELLOW</option>
    <option value="015">3 - YELLOW</option>
    <option value="016">4 - YELLOW</option>
    <option value="017">1 - BLACK</option>
    <option value="018">2 - BLACK</option>
    <option value="019">3 - BLACK</option>
    <option value="020">4 - BLACK</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in line

```
$("select[name="B"] option[value=" + vList[i] + "]").remove();
```

`B`, instead of part of string value, becomes a variable, placed between two strings without operators. It should be, for example:

```
$("select[name='B'] option[value=" + vList[i] + "]").remove();
```

Also, I changed `click` event handler from

```
$('select[name="A"] option[value="001"]').click
```

to

```
$('select[name="A"]').change
```

with checking for selected value inside event handler for proper `select` changed value handling.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1xLgxzz/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('select[name="A"]').change(function()
    {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        if (selected == '001')
        {
            var vList = ["001", "002", "003", "004"];
            $.each(vList, function(i, code)
            {
                $("select[name='B'] option[value=" + vList[i] + "]").remove();
             });
        }
     });
});
```

And one more thing: instead of `$("document")` you can write `$(document)`.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue!  It also led me to some interesting discussion between .click() and .change().

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[name="A"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() === '001'){
            var vList = ["001", "002", "003", "004"];
            $.each(vList, function(i, code){
                $('select[name="B"] option[value="' + code + '"]').remove();
            });
        }     
    });
 });
```

I tested this code in Chrome

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/msbtgecg/)